# AdMobs causes project error: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to add adMob to my Android project.

When I add `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar` to libs folder it gives me a dialog that contains this text

> Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application.

and in console, it gives me this message

```
Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/ads/AdRequest$ErrorCode;
```

Consider that I added the `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar` in Build path and did clean and restarted the eclipse and it still gives me the error. Also I'm using 'google-play-services_lib' because my app is Google Map Api V2.

When I remove the `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar` from libs folder, the app runs and gives me ClassNotFound Exception.

Comment: open your project.properties file and change target to 13.

Comment: I'm using Google API level 17. I edited the question. see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it, The Problem was because I was trying to add `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar` while using `google-play-services_lib` I done like what in this [link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?hl=nl#play-xml) and it now works